# Multi joins Acess

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

Yes I've read the articles currently posted, and no, I can't figure this out.

I have multiple joins occurring, and I'm not entirely sure where the `()` go or where the `SET` should go ideally.

Here is my attempt:

```
UPDATE authormash  
INNER JOIN article ON authormash.articletitle = article.articletitle SET authormash.articleid = article.articleid 
INNER JOIN article ON authormash.volume = article.volume
INNER JOIN article ON authormash.issue = article.issue
```

Comment: huh? Why do you join the same table three times?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the purpose of the JOIN, because there are duplicates in the first join clause, I added others to ensure the join is unique...?

Comment: Why not lookup the [update syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp) instead of guessing or posting a question? Its not very complex .

Comment: Maybe update the question with a basic schema.

Answer (score 0):

The whole purpose of a `JOIN` is to combine two tables information based on what is common between them.

**This is your original code:**

```
UPDATE authormash  
INNER JOIN article ON authormash.articletitle = article.articletitle 
SET authormash.articleid = article.articleid 
INNER JOIN article ON authormash.volume = article.volume
INNER JOIN article ON authormash.issue = article.issue
```

It appears that you want to Update `authormash` with some data in `article` and the common denominator between them is `articleid`.

**Here is what it appears you want to achieve:**

```
update am
set am.volume= a.volume
--additional sets can go here
from authormash am
    inner join articles a on
        am.articletitle = a.articletitle
```

**you can always add more SET statements this way**

```
, am.issue = a.issue
```

You can include a `WHERE` clause if you need to filter the data.

If you can update the question with more details I can always update the answer accordingly. Hope this helps you. Welcome to SQL.

Comment: Does this help?